# Which grammatical case is "him" in "I help him", and why?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

In languages which distinguish the accusative and dative cases, it is clear from the actual usage whether a divalent verb takes a direct or indirect object. For example, the German *eat* takes a direct object ("ich esse ihn"), while *help* takes an indirect object ("ich helfe ihm").

How do you know what kind of object an English verb takes? Which case is the object pronoun in the phrase "I help him"?

Edit: I'm looking for a reason to say that it, without doubt, is an accusative or dative pronoun. The reason for the German example is that the English accusative and dative pronouns are degenerate, and it therefore is easy to claim something -- you can't disprove it with an example.

Comment: Regarding your edit: are you really looking to figure out if it's an accusative or dative pronoun (I would argue that it's neither (or both)), or are you trying to determine whether the objective pronoun is being used as an indirect or direct object?

Comment: If you really get a reason to decide one way or the other "without doubt", then get a paper written-- there's currently no consensus on this among scholars.

Comment: @Dusty: I thought those two questions were equivalent, i.e. that an direct/indirect pronoun always is in accusative/dative form. If they're not, feel free to explain and edit my question to make more sense.

Comment: @Neil: That's interesting, do you know of any papers on this debate?

Answer (score 12):

English doesn't really have a concept of direct versus indirect object in the same way.

To answer the easy part of the question: both *eat* and *help* take direct objects in English.

While there are some verbs (which I'll come to next) that some people analyse as taking both a direct and indirect object, for the most part English uses prepositions where other languages might use a dative or indirect object - so we say things like

> I said "hello" *to him*.
>
> I did the washing *for him*.
>
> I mentioned your name *to her*.

Some verbs (such as *tell, hand, give, show*) can express two objects without using a preposition. It *is* possible to call one of these objects direct and the other indirect (and indeed people often do - not least because it's useful to have names to distinguish the two objects), but in many ways it is better to analyse them as being *ditransitive* (that is, taking two direct objects). For example:

> I told ¹him ²the news.
>
> I handed ¹her ²the book.
>
> I gave ¹them ²a cheese and pickle sandwich.
>
> I showed ¹you ²the way to use the chainsaw.
>
> That saved ¹me ²a fortune.

These can usually also be expressed with a preposition:

> I told ²the news ¹to him.
>
> I handed ²the book ¹to her.
>
> I gave ²a cheese and pickle sandwich ¹to them.
>
> I showed ²the house ¹to you.
>
> That saved ²a fortune ¹for me.

In the case without prepositions, the so-called "indirect" object is generally the one that comes first (though there are dialects in which saying *I gave it you* is correct for *I gave it to you*, and similarly for the other verbs).

In the case where these verbs are used with a single object, it is usually understood as the indirect object (the one that would naturally follow the verb even if there were two objects), but this is not grammatical for some verbs, and for other verbs what follows is a direct object (sometimes with a different meaning):

> I told him. (single object "indirect")
>
> *I handed her. (ungrammatical)
>
> *I gave them. (ungrammatical)
>
> I showed you. (single object "indirect")
>
> That saved me. (grammatical, but with different meaning)
>
> He threw me the ball. / He threw the ball (single object is "direct")
>
> He brought me a turnip. / He brought a turnip (single object is "direct") / He brought me. (grammatical, but with different meaning)

Why consider both objects as direct objects? One reason is that there is no distinction in object pronouns; "them" is used in both the "direct" and "indirect" positions. English simply does not have a concept of "dative", even in pronouns (which retain more case distinctions than standard nouns). For another: in languages that have true indirect objects, it is not usually possible to transform the sentence into the passive voice with the indirect object as subject, at least not without some sort of rephrasing. This is not true with English, since either object can, in most cases, become the subject of a passive:

> He was told the news by me. / The news was told to him by me.
>
> The book was handed to her by me. / She was handed the book by me.
>
> A sandwich was given to them by me. / They were given a sandwich by me.
>
> ?I was saved a fortune by that. (questionable) / A fortune was saved for me by that. (grammatical, but with a slightly different meaning)

So, finally, to address your last two questions:

*How do you know what kind of object an English verb takes?* It may take zero, one or two direct objects, and possibly other complements with prepositions - but you have to learn all of these along with the meaning of the verb; there's no easy way out I'm afraid.

*Which case is the object pronoun in the phrase "I help him"?* The word *him* here is the objective case - and indeed *him* always is; there is no concept of direct or indirect object pronouns.

Comment: +1 Two remarks: 1. In Greek, the secondary complement of a verb can become subject if the sentence is changed into passive even with dative (and genitive) complements, just as in English; and the cases are very clearly marked, including dative v. accusative. So *pisteuô autôi* ("I trust/believe him [dative]") could be changed into *ho tyrannos pisteuetai* ("the monarch [nominative] is trusted/believed"). 2. Another test might be: could you replace the object (x) with *to x* or *for x*? If yes, it is probably an indirect object to those who distinguish direct and indirect objects.

Comment: +1 Great answer. The only thing I take issue with is *“In the case where these verbs are used with a single object, it is almost always understood as the indirect object.”* This seems to vary from verb to verb. Many verbs are understood the other way: *I brought them sandwiches / I brought sandwiches*; *I offered him $5 / I offered $5*; *He tossed me the ball / He tossed the ball*.

Comment: Thanks. As to your answer to the specific question, I was wondering which whether _him_ is in accusative or dative case. Are you saying that it is a pointless question because those cases are degenerate in English?

Comment: @Jason: Good point! I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Cerberus: Interesting... I knew when I wrote that someone would come up with a counterexample (hence the "usually"), so thank you :) Does this apply to all verbs, or just *πιστευω*? I notice Liddle & Scott gloss passive use of this verb explicitly, whereas if it were a common use of the passive I might not expect them to... so for example to say "I was helped" can I transform *ὁ Κερβερος βοηθει ἐμοι* to *βοηθouμαι* (or whatever the right verb forms are, it's been a long time!)

Comment: @Tim: Basically, yes - the dative is not just degenerate: the Old English dative case hasn't existed for so long that the concept of "dative" simply doesn't exist in the language today...

Comment: @psmears: I believe you may find it with several common verbs; Greek grammar is usually quite flexible, at least compared to Latin. I think this construction is possible whenever there is no reason not to, such as the ambiguity that might arise when the middle form of the verb already has a different meaning. You can see that L&S mention the passive construction with *epithumeô* too. It may be that L&S consider these verbs exceptions, though I think there would be many, then; or perhaps they mention the passive only where its meaning is a bit more specialised than one would normally expect.

Comment: Notice that, for verbs that take two objects, the second one cannot be replaced by a pronoun without reordering. For example, when you replace the objects in "*I sent Mary the book.*" with pronouns, you can say "*I sent her the book.*" but you would have to say "*I sent it to Mary.* "

Comment: @psmears: I don't know about *boêtheô* specifically; it may be restricted for some reason. But I'd not be surprised. Your verb forms are fine!

Comment: @Peter Shor: True (although there do exist dialects in which "I sent it Mary" or even "I sent Mary it" are acceptable :)

Comment: @Cerberus: Thanks for the info, very interesting :) (and I'm not sure how I managed to get the verbs right, but mis-spell "Liddell" this morning :-/ )

Comment: @psmears: Haha yes, I misspell him all the time; that is, I have to look him up every time (I am a Latin guy). Only now do I notice that I typed "L&S" without blinking: that should have been LSJ (L&S = Lewis & Short)! // I just found out that the LSJ version on Tufts ("Perseus") does mention passive *boêtheô*! Were you using the Harvard ("Archimedes/Pollux") version as well (I was)? That is strange, because they are both supposed to be the 1940 edition (I once asked Harvard in an e-mail). http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dbohqe%2Fw

Answer (score 2):

There is only a slight grammatical distinction between direct and indirect objects in English. Indirect objects can’t be moved around in a sentence quite as freely.

> *He asked if I bought Kaitlin presents.* (ok)
>
> *He asked what I bought Kaitlin.* (DO preposed - ok)
>
> *He asked who I bought presents.* (IO preposed - wrong)
>
> *I gave her a headache.* (ok)
>
> *[The headache I gave her] hasn’t gone away.* (DO preposed - ok)
>
> *[The woman I gave a headache] hasn’t gone away.* (IO preposed - iffy)

But there is no such distinction between *eat* and *help*:

> *[The pancakes I ate] were pretty good.* (single object preposed - ok)
>
> *[The student I helped] was pretty good.* (single object preposed - ok)

So grammatically, there is simply no grammatical distinction to be made here. We say that both *eat* and *help* take a direct object.

The same is true about verbs like *tell* that can take a single object with either meaning:

> *[The secrets I told] weren’t pretty.* (single object preposed - ok)
>
> *[The man I told] wasn’t pretty.* (single object preposed - ok)

Regardless of the semantic role of the single object, it’s syntactically a direct object.

**Update —** I completely rewrote this after reading the bits of *[CGEL](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/sample.htm)* about indirect objects (chapter 4, §4).

Comment: Can you back that statement up? Why would it be so?

Comment: The case of a direct object is accusative.

Comment: @Tim OK, I backed it up with an example. If you try to omit the direct object, as in *I sent him*, you'll find that you’ve only succeeded in making *him* the direct object.

Comment: @Jason: The problem with this reasoning is that you could apply the same arguments to German, where the conclusion would be false. I'd like some authoritative source to support your claim that a sentence with an indirect object always contains a direct object.

Comment: (I don't disagree with you about your example, but it's just an example.)

Comment: Only argument from authority will satisfy you? I'll see what I can find.

Comment: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/indirectobject.htm “For an indirect object to appear, a sentence must first have a direct object.”

Comment: http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000018.htm “There must be a direct object to have an indirect object.”

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28grammar%29 “There must be a direct object for an indirect object to be placed in a sentence.”

Comment: The problem with citing internet authorities on matters of grammar is that they’re wrong even more often than I am. ;-)

Comment: @Jason: You are right that such sources won't count :) The Wikipedia link is even wrong, since it claims that your statement is true for all languages, while it isn't.

Comment: Note that if you take the traditional view that a *to* prepositional phrase is an indirect object, then indirect objects so marked do occur in clauses with no direct object: *He gives to the poor.* I consider these to be intransitive uses.

Comment: As evidence for that last statement, verbs like *leave* with a sharp difference in meaning between the ditransitive (*He left his daughters a fortune*) and the intransitive (*He left*) can’t be used with a *to* prepositional phrase, and no direct object, with the ditransitive interpretation: *He left to his daughters* is baffling.

Comment: _He left to Las Vegas_ :)

Comment: @Tim: It is really hard to prove a negative. :) *[CGEL](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/)*, chapter 4 §5: “In canonical clauses containing just one object, that object is always a direct object, even if it corresponds semantically to the indirect object of a ditransitive clause. [...] Except in certain non-canonical constructions (such as the passive), therefore, Oi is found only in combination with Od.”

Comment: @Tim Yes, that’s my point! *He left to Las Vegas* can only be interpreted as the intransitive *leave*, not the ditransitive one.

Comment: The passive construction *CGEL* is talking about is this one: ? *A copy was sent Sue.*  Here *a copy* is the subject and *Sue* is indirect object. Marginal at best, but it does happen.

Comment: What about the following?  *"Who told Sue about her father's death?" "I told her"*

Comment: @Dusty: In the question, *Who* is subject, *Sue* is direct object, and *her father's death* is the object of the preposition *about*. In the response, *I* is subject and *her* is direct object.

Comment: @Jason Orendorff - Sorry, I meant just the response, the other was just a setup.  I would have suggested that *her* in *I told her* is the IO (with the implicit news of her father's death being the DO) If *her* is a DO in that sentence, what about *I told her the news*?

Comment: @Dusty You are right, the stuff in my answer about monotransitive *send* having to mean a certain thing is totally bogus. Fixing it.

Comment: Hi folks, this thread is now getting auto-flagged by the system. Please take longish discussions to our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage). You don't have to be logged on there at the same time, just keep @-mentioning each other just like on the main site. You can then summarize the results here, either by updating the answer or by posting a concluding comment or two (but not thirty). Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/help#Verb, help can be a transitive verb or an intransitive verb, so "him" would be accusative case.

(Edited)

Comment: Why do you think that a transitive verb only takes a direct object?

Comment: Wouldn't a transitive verb _have_ to take a direct object, though?  According to Jason, if you only have one object, it's the direction object.

Comment: While I agree that help can be either transitive or intransitive and that 'him' would fall in the accusative case, it's unclear to me how the former implies the latter.

Comment: @Dusty: If a transitive verb has an object, that object must be the direct object; it won't be the indirect object (at least if Jason is right on that count).

Comment: @user: What I'm looking for is something to support that statement.