# Why "answer me" but not "answer me the question"?

Tags: archaicisms, transitive-verbs, indirect-objects, predicate-frames, dative-alternation

Why are "answer me" and "answer the question" acceptable but not "answer me the question"?  Is it similar to "explain me (something)"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What's wrong with “I'll open you the door”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door)

Answer (score 9):

## [*Riddle me this, Batman.*](http://books.google.com/books?id=5hrOKmZv_AkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22riddle+me+this%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sSNBUfetLuXEyQHrqoHICQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw)

***Sometimes*** it  actually ***is*** ok to “answer me a question”. Acceptability may vary.  For example, this sounds fine to me:

> If you can answer me this next question, you can go free.

Here are several examples from Google Books, all of which sound find to my ear:

- [I want you to answer me this question. What is your heart made of? He mocked  her.](http://books.google.com/books?id=Hrj5MpOg0cAC&pg=PA58&dq=%22answer+me+this%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=URhBUcqKPMfyyAHP64C4AQ&ved=0CFUQ6AEwDA)
- [Do answer me this question, if you please?' The exasperated dwarf returned no  answer, but turned round and caught up his usual weapon with such vehemence,  that Tom Scott dragged his charge away, by main force, and as swiftly as he ...](http://books.google.com/books?id=_K_e6qKfyGkC&pg=PT598&dq=%22answer+me+this%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=URhBUcqKPMfyyAHP64C4AQ&ved=0CF0Q6AEwDg) [Charles Dickens]
- [Well, then, Bernadette, answer me this. Do you know what they're going to think  in Hanoi when they learn that the children of the officers of this country's military  are protesting the war?](http://books.google.com/books?id=SWnmgIJ2_NIC&pg=PA104&dq=%22answer+me+this%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=URhBUcqKPMfyyAHP64C4AQ&ved=0CIUBEOgBMBg)
- [Come, then, and answer me what difference it makes whether I present Paul  speaking in my way, or a commentator says 'this is what Paul means,' and goes  on to give his own explanation.](http://books.google.com/books?id=SvGbiGIqz74C&pg=PA81&dq=%22answer+me+what%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XBlBUY31CIrSygHYzIGQAQ&ved=0CJ4DEOgBMFk)
- ["Wait jest a minute, duke— answer me this one question, honest and fair; if you  didn't put the money there, say it, and I'll b'lieve you, and take back everything I  said."](http://books.google.com/books?id=m_jYhQNdBUsC&pg=PA136&dq=%22answer+me+this%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=URhBUcqKPMfyyAHP64C4AQ&ved=0CJYBEOgBMBw) [Mark Twain]
- [Then he said: 'Can you answer me this one? Why is the county of Kildare like the  leg of a fellow's breeches?'](http://books.google.com/books?id=_ILE9B-c6uUC&pg=PA28&dq=%22answer+me+this%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=URhBUcqKPMfyyAHP64C4AQ&ved=0CKIBEOgBMB8) [James Joyce]
- ["You answer me one question, there, Kali girl," he says quietly, the dangerous,  angry drunk gone for a moment, replaced by a sad, dejected man. "Answer me one question, and if you answer it right, I'll go. Okay?"](http://books.google.com/books?id=i1UQ_Sejsu4C&pg=PA149&dq=%22answer+me+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RxhBUffdD6OdyQGWoIDQCQ&ved=0CEUQ6AEwCQ)
- [“Answer me one thing before you go. One thing, and tell me the truth. Have you  ever been in love?”](http://books.google.com/books?id=v9kO-0kC-xYC&pg=PA24&dq=%22answer+me+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RxhBUffdD6OdyQGWoIDQCQ&ved=0CFAQ6AEwDA)
- ["I will tell you that if you will first answer me one question, Rima."](http://books.google.com/books?id=CZagQ1wutQwC&pg=PA68&dq=%22answer+me+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RxhBUffdD6OdyQGWoIDQCQ&ved=0CFsQ6AEwDw)
- [Answer me one word  — is it this mysterious stranger whom your father honours with his friendship?](http://books.google.com/books?id=GAwGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA52&dq=%22answer+me+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RxhBUffdD6OdyQGWoIDQCQ&ved=0CJEBEOgBMBw)
- [“Before I draw nearer to that stone to which you point,” said Scrooge, “answer me one question. Are these the shadows of the things that will be, or are they  shadows of the things that may be, only?”](http://books.google.com/books?id=65igxUfqkQUC&pg=PA349&dq=%22answer+me+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RxhBUffdD6OdyQGWoIDQCQ&ved=0CKEBEOgBMCA) [Charles Dickens]
- [Before I reply," said Preciosa, "you must answer me one thing, by the life of the  one you most love."](http://books.google.com/books?id=W60RAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA271&dq=%22answer+me+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RxhBUffdD6OdyQGWoIDQCQ&ved=0CLgBEOgBMCY) [Edgar Allen Poe]
- [The incognita, however, shook her head with a mournful, abstracted air, and did  not answer him one word.](http://books.google.com/books?id=24tHAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA709&dq=%22answer+him+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WB5BUe2IIejhyQGgtoDICQ&ved=0CIgDEOgBMFs)
- [And did you answer him his question? —I answered him a  few questions.](http://books.google.com/books?id=QFE1AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA444&dq=%22answer+him+his+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NhlBUeG5E4LzygGFtoCoCQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAg)
- [Listen to me," coming a step nearer, " before I go you shall answer me one  question.](http://books.google.com/books?id=zEwZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA70&dq=%22shall+answer+me+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kSJBUapOpuDJAfTjgeAF&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ)
- [I told him be had intimated that two or three times to me; that if he would answer me two questions, I would then listen to him.](http://books.google.com/books?id=oLEBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA404&dq=%22answer+me+two%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3SJBUdTfKKXKyQGm7oCIDA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBg)
- ['Noble count,' said Marco, 'answer me two questions, and I shall receive these  gifts in pay for your answers.'](http://books.google.com/books?id=7C3QAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA100&dq=%22answer+me+two%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3SJBUdTfKKXKyQGm7oCIDA&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCg) [Mary Shelley]
- [“You answer me three questions and then I will let you know how excited I am for  you.”](http://books.google.com/books?id=GMqiW6c6NrgC&pg=PA188&dq=%22answer+me+three%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aSNBUdzWNqT9ygG04YEg&ved=0CEIQ6AEwCA)

---

### Previous Answer

The simple answer is because we no longer talk that way. Here’s a rather famous quote that uses the very thing you have asked about:

> *“He who would cross the Bridge of Death must **answer me these questions three** ere the other side he see.”*

As you might detect, that is a valid but archaic  formulation. (Another sign of deliberate archaism there is the present subjunctive following *ere*.)

The OED has several transitive senses of *answer*, but almost all are marked either archaic or indeed even obsolete, especially the bitransitive ones.

Here are a few such examples from the OED:

> - 1581 Charke in *Confer*. iv. (1584) F f b, - You haue so often chalenged vs to answere you an argument.
> - 1594 Shaks. *Rich. III*, iv. ii. 96 - Stanley looke to your Wife: if she conuey Letters to Richmond, you shall answer it.
> - 1625 Donne *Serm*. cl. Wks. VI. 61 - Whosoever is dead in that family by thy negligence, thou shall answer the King that subject.
> - 1731 Swift *Corr*. II. 649 - The maid will..sell more butter and cheese than will answer her wages.
> - 1793 Smeaton *Edystone L.* §125 - The Proprietors could not answer it to the public..if they kept me in waiting.

Comment: +1 But the archaic formula is preserved–fossilized, you may say–in the still-current "Answer me that!"

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, the imperative form preserves it, as I have just pointed out to John.

Comment: @StoneyB Actually, it appears that you can get away with it when modals are involved, too: [check this out](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22must%20answer%20me%20one%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1904,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en). Similarly [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22answer+me+this%22&btnG=Search&tbs=bks%3A1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1904%2Ccd_max%3A2008&lr=lang_en).

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that, while *answer* **is** a transitive predicate, and therefore has a direct object (referring **either** to the question that was answered **or** the addressee of the answer -- **but not both** at the same time); nevertheless *answer* is **not** a bitransitive predicate, and therefore has no indirect object.

- *I told the number to Bill* ~ *I told Bill the number*
- *I sent the book to Bill* ~ *I sent Bill the book.*
  (bitransitive verbs, direct & indirect objects, and [Dative Alternation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/106899/15299))
- *I fixed the socket* ~ **I fixed the socket to Bill* ~ **I fixed Bill the socket*
- *I answered the question* ~ **I answered the question to Bill* ~ **I answered Bill the question*
  (transitive verbs w/ direct object, but no indirect object, therefore no Dative Alternation)

Comment: Answer me one question, please: is there anything wrong with this sentence? :)

Comment: Fixed forms exist. Answer yourself your question.

Answer (score 2):

The more complicated answer is a *lot* of people don't accept that *answer* can be [ditransitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb) (i.e. - they don't think it can validly modify both *me* and *the question* in OP's example).

I'm not going to say they're *wrong* - I'm perfectly happy with [I'll open you the door](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door), for example, but fairly obviously most people aren't.

But I would say that in the case of [in?] *question*, it's worth noting there are apparently over half-a-million written instances in Google Books of...

> [Answer me this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22answer%20me%20this%20question%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22answer%20me%20this%22&oq=%22answer%20me%20this%22&gs_l=serp.3...733956.736759.0.737279.11.11.0.0.0.0.111.744.9j2.11.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.wq3O5l9dRXM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.d2k&fp=37f67e2c6bb8a774&biw=1308&bih=844)

...so if it *is* wrong, a lot of people either don't know that, or don't care. I think many verbs are "marginal" in this respect, and that *answer* is considered "ditransitive" by a significant minority.

---

For reasons that aren't fully clear to me, people are more prepared to "stretch" marginal verbs when the additional indirect object is ***me***. So **"I answered Bill the question"* sounds bad to people who don't mind *"Answer me that!"*

I think it's probably connected with the fact that forms like *"Give me the money!"* are acceptable to all because the indirect object *(me)* is a *recipient*. When you say *"Answer me that!"*, what you really mean is *"Give me an answer to that!"*. Semantically, *answer* serves as a "giving" verb, allowing it to be used ditransitively.

The specific indirect object *me* probably figures disproportionately high in the total number of utterances a person makes (we're always saying variants of *"Give me this!"* and *"Give me that!"*). My guess is that predisposes at least some of us to accept *"Answer me that!"* more easily than **"Answer Bill the question!"*

Comment: I’ve found quite a few others in Google Books, too, like “Answer me what difference it makes. . . .” It also seems to work if there is a modal like *must* or *will* before it: “You will answer me one last question before you leave here, young man.”  This is almost always with “answer me”; instances of “answer him his question” are much rarer.

Comment: What, you think people would have a problem with “Open me one of those packages, please”?  Odd.

Comment: @tchrist: It's not a matter of what ***I*** think. Check the link, count the votes for the top answers, *then* tell me other people don't have a problem with some of these usages. Anyway, unless I'm much mistaken, you yourself had a problem with *"I'll cash you a cheque"*. Even if you personally don't, an awful lot of Americans do.

Comment: I assure that my only problem with you cashing me a check is completely limited to its spelling.  No really, cash me a check sounds fine.

Comment: @tchrist: The spelling of *cheque/check* was precisely what prompted me to use that one in [my answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/90531/2637) to the linked question. The two top answers (saying such forms are not valid) currently have 85 votes between them; mine (saying they *are* valid) has 4 votes. Like I say, I'm only reporting what other people think, since obviously I don't agree with them.